# Is there a way to intersect real-valued column with a sparse column?

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression

`crossed_column` is able to intersect a few sparse (categorical) columns. Is there a way to intersect a real-valued column with a sparse column in a `LinearRegressor` ? The mathematical meaning of this seems clear: I need different weights at continuous feature X, depending on a categorical feature Z.